# How did they make The homepage of canva.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, blur

I was browsing through random websites when i came across this site called [canva.com](http://www.canva.com) and its homepage interested me a lot. It has a blurred background and when you hover through it, it becomes sharp. I tried to check out its source code but, could not figure out how they did it?

I tried to check the background image when the mouse is hovered and every time i check it, it is a different background image for different position. I don't think that the designer made all possible images and uploaded, that would not be efficient perhaps. I think that the images are dynamically generated.

Anyone else have any idea as to how it can be done?? Please check it out.

Comment: I'm thinking some canvas magic.

Comment: They use a blurred background image, a canvas and an unblurred version of the image. Moving the mouse 'draws' (a portion of) the sharp image onto an otherwise transparent canvas. This makes it look like some kind of magic, when in reality it's just selectively copying a src image onto a canvas. I imagine a second, off-screen canvas is used to allow the 'drawn' lines to have their opacity faded. This canvas is then used to blend the copied image with the blurred image. Look into "canvas blending modes".

Comment: HTML5 [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, Need to study more on HTML5 canvas. Your comment were of big help